# Most number of Oscars won by a sound designer, re-recording mixer, editor ..

Tags: academy-awards, sound-design, mixing, sound-editing

I was just curious to know .. Who has won the most number of oscars for sound? 
I know Gary Rydstrom has won 7 .. but is he the only one to have won these many? or are there few more?

Comment: Well I know Kevin O'Connell has 21 nominations and no wins.

Comment: a more difficult question (& in my humble opinion, a greater achievement) who has won an award for sound at Cannes?

Comment: (sorry I should start my own question)

Comment: Another good question would be "How many people who vote for the Academy Awards categories for sound are actually qualified to have a valid opinion on the matter?"  Anyone know the inside scoop on who actually votes? Are they peers and active in the industry? Or is it anyone with membership to the academy?

Comment: via google: Oscar voters are predominately white (94%) male (77%) & have average age of 62 :(

Comment: @tim prebble That explains many things... But kind of brings attention to what I suspected: How many of those voters really know the intricacies of certain movies vs. others? I'm not invalidating those who have won an Academy Award for sound, but I tend to think some movies don't get nominated that definitely should have, but just might not have been "popular" enough to garner the attention of said voters.. and which is why I think your comment on Cannes is spot on.

Comment: From their website: "They are the more than 6,000 artists and professionals who bring the magic of the movies to life. They are the men and women who transport audiences to galaxies far away and to worlds long ago and who create the previously unimagined for the big screen. They are the entertainment industry's preeminent filmmakers. They are Academy members."  Ironic how Star Wars has yet to win the big Best Film and Director categories, but they totally stole the tag line ;)

Comment: I agree with @tim prebble. The politics within the Academy is obvious. Another example is that of Leo DiCaprio, who's worked in so many blockbusters but yet to receive an Oscar. I'm afraid that in the coming years the Academy Awards are gonna lose its charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as far as I know, Gary Rydstrom is the one who has won the most number of Oscars for achievement in Sound. But still if you wan to know more about others too, you can look up [here](http://awardsdatabase.oscars.org/ampas_awards/BasicSearchInput.jsp). Hope that helps!